# Long load times on 10K tools ("flagged posts")

Tags: bug, 10k-tools, performance

In the last few days I've noticed that the ["Flagged Posts" page](https://stackoverflow.com/tools/flagged) has gone from loading instantly to hanging for 10-15 seconds before loading.

<s>This is the only page on the SO site on which I am seeing this behavior. In fact, it's the only page on SO on which I have *ever* noticed a slowdown.</s> As noted in the comments, I am  now also seeing a slowdown on /flag-summary. Perhaps I didn't notice it before.

The server execution of the page itself appears to be the bottleneck (screenshot):

[image]

I see this behavior in Chrome, Firefox (PC, latest) and Safari (Mac, latest). I brought up the full site on my mobile phone (iPhone 5, outside of my home wireless network) and observed similar behavior.

This is making it a little inconvenient to efficiently review posts, as I often jump back and forth between questions and the tools page. Please let me know if I can provide more detail or assist in diagnosing the problem.

**24 Hour Update:** I've accessed the pages in question at least 50 times since posting this to a) perform review tasks and b) confirm that the behavior is still occurring. I've also added the iPad to the list of devices on which I see similar performance.

I also tested from a virtual machine hosted in one of the larger data centers in the US. Again, most of the site is fast but /tools ("flags" tab) exhibits the same load time of roughly 10 seconds.

---

<sup>Note that I have tagged this as "bug" only in the interest of taxonomy; I'm hesitant to classify poor performance as a true bug, especially as it may already be known/explained.</sup>

Comment: I've been thinking that - but just put it down to the bandwith I'm on being used up - but now I'm certain nothing else is using it - yep, loading the flagged posts is taking a good 10secs+

Comment: I got the same for `users/flag-summary`, so it might more related to flag in general (not only on the mod tools).

Comment: @j0k - I'm seeing sporadic sluggishness on my flag summary as well. Not sure how long that has been going on; I check the flagged queue much more often.

Comment: My flag summary page has been sluggish loading since Tuesday

Comment: I'm just adding a comment to confirm this is still happening... it's getting a little bit frustrating now :(

Comment: Just to say, we know, we are also effected, and we _are_ looking into it.

Comment: @Oded - FYI, this is looking much better over the past 24 hours. Whenever you want to post an answer with an update saying that the problem is officially fixed, I'll mark it as accepted.

Comment: I didn't do any work on this, so can't take any credit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I pushed some changes this morning to greatly improve this - though it is a temporary solution.  Jarrod is working on a massive refactor of how flags are stored that will allow us to *greatly* improve efficiency on the queries (and many other things, but that's a good benefit).  When those changes are in we'll do another round of tuning and get performance even better - hang on for that in the new few weeks.

Comment: Thanks for the fixes; temporary or not, they make the impacted areas usable again.